# Installing NERDTree on Windows

Tags: windows, vim, nerdtree, vim-plugin

I'm trying to install NERDTree (the Vim plugin) on Windows 7. I created a .vim directory on my user folder (C:/Users/Username) and extracted the plugin there. I've run :helptags ~.vim\doc and :helptags [full-path]. Closed and reopened Vim.

But when I try:

```
:NERDTree
```

the editor says:

```
E492: Not an editor command: NERDTree
```

How should I do it?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Windows doesn't use the '.vim' style directories.  Instead you should put addons in directory structure branching off a vimfiles directory at one of two places:

c:\users\username\vimfiles\

or

c:\program files (x86)\vim\vimfiles\

For a little more help you can do `:h runtimepath`, and you could even modify runtimepath to make it work with your .vim directory, but safest route is just to go with the default vimfiles name oon Windows.

Comment: Thank you, every tutorial I've seen doesn't mention this!

Answer (score 7):

try extracting the file to vimfiles instead of .vim

Answer (score 1):

None of the other answers worked for me, so I did the following:

- The contents of directory ‘doc’ gets copied to: `C:\Program
  Files\Vim\vimXX\doc`
- The directory ‘nerdtree_plugin’ is copied to
  `C:\Program Files\Vim\vimXX\`
- The contents of directory ‘plugin’ is
  copied to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vimXX\plugin\`

Where XX is your vim version number. Works for 7.4

Source [http://shawn.hamman.co.nz/](http://shawn.hamman.co.nz/2011/08/getting-shit-done-on-windows-part-2-2-using-nerdtree-to-level-up-your-awesome/)

Comment: This did not work for me. I also tried the Vim 8+ plugin support, that didn't work. I'm installing on Windows 10 with Vim 9. Any help is greatly appreciated.